Can Friedel-Crafts acylation work with phosgene or HCOCl?
I understand from the textbook that acetyl chloride would work just fine with $\ce{AlCl3}$ catalyst, but how about phosgene or $\ce{HCOCl}$? Phosgene looks very unstable and I'm wondering if it can FC acylate with a benzene to form a benzoyl chloride, and the other molecule to form benzaldehyde? Or would side reactions prevent it? And if it can acylate does it need a catalyst at all since it's so electrophilic?

Phosgene isn't unstable, but HCOCl is - CO + HCl is used instead.

What do you think benzyl chloride will do in presence of excess benzene and AlCl3?

@user55119 benzoyl chloride?

@Oscar Lanzi: OOPS!

@user55119 in ochem1, i feel the world is vast and the possibility of new interactions unexpected. if side rxns dont prevent it, i wonder if the product would rxt w the initial reagents and no longer be a major prodct. according to lanzi, it seems there may be

@dreamstate: Oscar Lanzi is correct. My typing "benzyl choride" was a brain freeze.

The standard mode for Friedel-Crafts acylation with phosgene is indeed the phosgene is the acylating reagent. One stage of reaction produces the aryl acyl chloride; the second chloride moiety can also react giving a diaryl ketone.
$\ce{\underset{benzene}{C6H6} + COCl2 \overset{AlCl3}{->}\underset{benzoyl chloride}{C6H5COCl}}$
$\ce{C6H6 + C6H5COCl \overset{AlCl3}{->}\underset{benzophenone}{C6H5COC6H5}}$
This works only where the arene does not have Lewis-base functions such as a hydroxyl group, for these would attack the carbonyl group in the phosgene directly and you would get products such as carbonates (from a hydroxyl group).
Note that this answer concentrates on phosgene as the carbonyl source. Formyl chloride, $\ce{HCOCl}$, is too unstable to be isolated..

I see, can conditions be modified to prevent the 2nd rxn (forming benzophenone) from happening or is the 2nd rxn minor so it wouldnt take much away from yields?
also, is there a textbook i can reference for further readings?
Thank you for the information on formyl chloride

It seems that if CS2 is included as solvent in a ratio of 4:1 with benzene, that benzoyl chloride : benzophenone would be produced in a 3.47:1 ratio, or 77.6% yield. Seems like it would work then. Source: https://ia600708.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/28/items/crossref-pre-1923-scholarly-works/10.1021%252Fie50143a041.zip&file=10.1021%252Fie50149a012.pdf

@dreamstate: One way to minimizing benzophenone formation is to add benzene slowly to a large excess of phosgene and AlCl3 in an inert solvent.
